# Do I need parseInt if I want to sort numeric object keys?

Tags: javascript

I need to sort object keys as integers, they are all known to be integers for sure. (Set with a number variable like in the example).

This is not really a problem, I am just curious.

```
var steps = {}
steps[1] = true
steps[9] = true
steps[3+2] = true
steps[40] = true
var unsorted = Object.keys(steps), sorted = unsorted
    .map(function(a){ return parseInt(a) })
    .sort(function(a, b){ return a - b })
console.log(sorted)
```

Above, do I need that line with `map` and `parseInt`? If I comment out the line, everything *seems* to be OK. But I am unsure. Are there circumstances where usage of `parseInt` can make difference?

Comment: `-` will coerce to numbers, that's why it still works.

Comment: Note that parseInt and `-` have slightly different behavior. Try with a key of `"010"`. This is why parseInt should generally always be used with a radix (or conversion should be forced through other means).

Comment: Note that Object keys (including Array keys) are **always** Strings, even if you use a Number to specify them. So `steps[1]` is stored as `steps['1']`.

Comment: +1 for not just assuming it would work because one test didn't fail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No you don't need to parse keys to numbers explicetely since [substraction operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.6.2) does it for you anyway. From the spec:

> ...
>   5. Let *lnum* be ToNumber(*lval*).
>   6. Let *rnum* be ToNumber(*rval*).

so both operands are converted to Number type.

Your code can be

```
var unsorted = Object.keys(steps),
    sorted = unsorted.sort(function(a, b) { return a - b; });
```

Comment: funny how I knew every piece of knowledge you post here, but was not able to put it all together in my mind.

Comment: Well glad this question helped you to integrate your knowledge!

Answer (score 1):

It's okay to do the following :)

```
.sort((a, b) => parseInt(a) - parseInt(b))
```